# How to reset MUI input field to null from outside the react component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-context

So I have a parent component that includes a filter component and a delete button, so what I am trying to achieve is that, on the click of the "reset" button the filter component resets it's input value to null.

parent component housing multiple material ui components

```
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' ,bgcolor:"white",gap:"1.25rem",alignItems:"center", justifyContent:"center", borderRadius:"1.5rem",padding:"1rem 0rem",margin:"0.5rem 11rem" }}  >
        <LocationInput  setTempObj={setTempObj} />
        <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem/>
        <DateInput  setTempObj={setTempObj} />
        <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem/>
        <PriceInput  setTempObj={setTempObj}/>
        <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem/>
        <TypeInput  setTempObj={setTempObj} />
        <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem/>
        <Box sx={{display:"flex"}} >
            <Button  handleClick={handleClick} customClass={"bg-violet-600 text-white hover:bg-violet-700 transition-all px-8 py-4 "} text={"Search"} />
            <Button handleClick={deleteAllFilters}  customClass={"bg-red-600 text-white hover:bg-red-700 transition-all "} text={"Reset"} />
        </Box>
    </Box>
  )
```

the child components that I want to reset are all Input labelled components.

for example lets take typeInput:

```
const [range, setRange] = React.useState("");
    const menuItems=[
      {
        text:'House',
      },
      {
        text:'Office',
      },
      {
        text:'Industry',
      }
    ];
    const handleChange = (event) => {
      setRange(event.target.value);
      const set=menuItems[event.target.value].text;
      setTempObj((prevState)=>({
        ...prevState,
        type:set,
      }))
    };

    

  return (
    <Box sx={{height:"100%"}}>
    <Typography fontWeight="600" variant='body1' color="gray" marginBottom="1rem" >
        Property Type
      </Typography>
    <FormControl sx={{minWidth: 120 }} size="small">
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={range}
        label=""
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {menuItems.map((item,index)=>{
          return(
            <MenuItem key={index} value={index}>{item.text}</MenuItem>
          )
        })}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  </Box>
```

I have no idea how i would be able to change state of the material ui component from outside the component. Solution for this particular component would most likely work for other components as well so,if anyone can help me with this particular component, it would work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, Harsh! I haven't sat down with your code but imagine you could write a `useEffect` hook with some prop in its dependency array that you manage in your parent component. In the hook, you could then set the state equal to that prop value whenever the prop's value changes from the parent.

Comment: Thanks it worked , i was panicking a lot and had no idea what to do <3